# How to go to a specific Tab View after performing an action with SwitUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm tying to build an application to manage a virtual datacenter (servers, firewall policies, load balancers...). I have two sections (using tab view). One shows a list of all the elements you have created in your datacenter. The other section is to create new elements. If we launch the app, we start in the list section. Then I try to create a new server. For that, I go to the Create section, click on Server and select a Size, here the first two issues I couldn't solve:

1. Why the options of the picker make a **small jump** to the top of the screen? How can I remove it?
2. There is **too much space** between the top of the screen and the options of the picker. How can remove it?

And the last issue I have is that after creating the server, I return to the Create section and I would like to **go directly to the List section**. How can I do it?

Here basic code to see the questions/issues I have. Thanks in advance for any help!

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
            CreateView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    Text("Create")
                }.tag(0)
            ListView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "cloud")
                    Text("List")
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}


struct CreateView: View {
    var body: some View {
         VStack{
           NavigationView{
               List{
                   NavigationLink(destination: CreateServerView()){
                       Text("Server")
                   }
                   Text("Firewall Policy")
                   Text("Load Balancer")
               }
               .navigationBarTitle("Select the element you want to create", displayMode: .inline)
           }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                Section(header: Text("Servers")){
                    Text("Server 1")
                    Text("Server 2")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Firewall policies")){
                    Text("Firewall 1")
                    Text("Firewall 2")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My virtual datacenter", displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
}

struct CreateServerView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var selectedFixServer = 0

    @State private var serverType = ["S", "M", "L", "XL"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Name of the server")){
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                }
                Picker(selection: $selectedFixServer, label: Text("Size")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< serverType.count) {
                        Text(self.serverType[$0])
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Create Server")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading:
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                },
            trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Create")
                }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use just such a variant, not .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()) for example?

Answer (score 2):

One variant is to use .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()), but I don't know if this suits you. With this decision 2 problems solves and you don't need much space for it:

[image]

now about:

> go directly to the List section

In your example I just make @Binding var selectedTab in **CreateServerView** and change it before dissmissing:

```swift
struct CreateServerView: View {
    // ...
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    // ...
        trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedTab = 1
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Create")
                })
// ...
}
```

you need to pass this variable and it'll go directly to the list after creating server

Comment: The binding did the trick. Thanks! Regarding the "small jump" is a good alternative what you proponed but not valid  for my purposes so in the real app there are many sizes, but that was solved by @asperi

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why the options of the picker make a small jump to the top of the screen? How can I remove it?
> 2. There is too much space between the top of the screen and the options of the picker. How can remove it?

It is because you created second NavigationView inside existed NavigationView. So to fix this just remove NavigationView in your CreateServerView (say replace it with VStack, etc.)

*Note*: when I experimented with your code I've also commented next two lines

```
//                .navigationBarTitle("")
//                .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Comment: in this case it's impossible to interact with picker in that way, (or needs to change **pickerStyle** too)

Comment: Thanks @Asperi. That solved the problem of the jump. Being honest, there is yet a small jump, in this case from left to right, but it is really small. Regarding the line you removed, seems to be an old fix needed in betas to make the navbar invisible. Now, it is not needed.